# square wave matlab code

Tags: fourier-analysis, matlab, signal-processing

I'm having some trouble generating a square wave in matlab via my equation.  Just wondering if anyone has some insight on what I am missing here in my code?  I was thinking I could easily generate a square wave with just a few harmonics but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Thanks

```
x = 0:0.001:10;
w = 2*pi*x;
n = 5;
wave = 0;
for i = 1:2:n
wave = wave + ((4*Vg)/(i*pi))*cos(i*w);
end
plot(x,wave)
```

thanks

Comment: What are x,w and Vg in your formula? Also, you are not building up an array with that formula, just a number.

Comment: I guess you need more than just $5$ sinusoidals to get a square wave. Try large `n = 100` or `n = 500`?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using a series representation to generate this square waves? Because there are more direct ways to output a series of 0's and 1's.

Comment: @Raskolnikov The variable `wave` is an array, because `cos(i*w)` returns an array for the array `w = 2*pi*(0:0.001:10)`.

Comment: @Ed: yes, but he/she edited his/her text since my comment has been posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> x = 0:0.001:10;
> x = x';
> n = 5;
> wave = zeros(size(x,1),1);
> for i = 1:2:n
>   wave = wave + cos(2*i*pi*x)/(2*i*pi);
> end
> plot(x,wave)
> ```

Two comments for `MATLAB` etiquette, it is better handling vector using column, since it is a lot faster, and pre-allocating a variable before entering the loop would make the program more readable and faster.

I don't know what your `Vg` is, but above code snippet should work, basically what it does is approximating a square wave $W$ by:
$$
W = \frac{1}{2\pi}\cos(2\pi x) + \frac{1}{6\pi}\cos(6\pi x)  
+ \frac{1}{10\pi}\cos(10\pi x) 
$$
The result doesn't look very nice because of your mysterious `Vg`:
[image: Cos wave]

But if you switch the cosine to sine, it would be more like a square wave:
[image: Sine wave]

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting.  Seems like the problem was that I was using cosine, instead of sine.  Didn't occur to me that it would be so different.  
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

At the end of your code, you come up with just a 1*1 array.
Moving the `plot(x,wave)` **in the for loop** and using `hold on` after that could do a rather sloppy fixing. Try `plot(x,wave,'*')` since the value of `n` is too small. Otherwise change `n` to about 1000.
Also please present the complete code(what are x,w,...)

Comment: I edited my above post to include the values of x and w. 

However, i tried the new code with your suggestions and still i can't get it to quite be a square wave even with     n = 1000.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version of your code that computes the wave-form with a single line of code:

```
x = 0:0.001:10;
w = 2*pi*x;
n = 5;
Vg = 1;
k = 1:2:n;

W = ((4*Vg/pi)./k)*(sin(kron(k',w)));
```

As other responders have mentioned, $\sin$ looks to work better.

Here is a plot for $n=1000$:

[image]